# Fast great circle for multiple points - Python geopy

Tags: python, geopy

Is it possible to speed up the `great_circle(pos1, pos2).miles` from `geopy` if using it for multiple thousand points?
I want to create something like a distance matrix and at the moment my machine needs 5 seconds for 250,000 calculations.
Actually `pos1` is always the same if it helps.

Another "restriction" in my case is that I only want all points `pos2` which have a distance less than a constant `x`. 
(The exact distance doesn't matter in my case)

Is there a fast method? Do I need to use a faster function than `great_circle` which is less accurate or is it possible to speed it up without losing accuracy?

**Update**
In my case the question is whether a point is inside a circle.
Therefore it is easily possible to first get whether a point is inside a square.

```
start = geopy.Point(mid_point_lat, mid_point_lon)
d = geopy.distance.VincentyDistance(miles=radius)
p_north_lat = d.destination(point=start, bearing=0).latitude
# check whether the given point lat is > p_north_lat
# and so on for east, south and west
```

Comment: Great circle is already an approximation - I don't know if there's any way to speed it up, at least not with Geopy alone.